# Delete from file a line containing a certain string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, line

I need to remove certain strings from my log files. Yes, I know this sounds backward, but for everyone's sanity, trust me: there's no way to avoid these useless notices from being written to log in the first place.

So to make my logs readable, such notices have to be deleted after being written.

Here's an example of the polluted log file:

```
ERROR - 2012-08-06 02:12:01 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: H1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/application/helpers/mpdf/mpdf.php 14242
ERROR - 2012-08-06 02:12:01 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: H1>>ID>> /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/application/helpers/mpdf/mpdf.php 14288
ERROR - 2012-08-06 02:12:01 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: H1 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/application/helpers/mpdf/mpdf.php 14242
ERROR - 2012-08-06 02:12:01 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: H1>>ID>> /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/application/helpers/mpdf/mpdf.php 14288
ERROR - 2012-08-06 02:12:01 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: DIV /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/application/helpers/mpdf/mpdf.php 14242
```

I want to remove lines that:

- contain 'Notice' AND
- contain 'Undefined' AND
- contain 'mpdf.php'

I believe something along these lines may be a start:

```
$dir = '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/application/logs/log-2012-07-07.php';

$content = file_get_contents($dir);

$new = preg_replace($pattern, '', $content) // <===== need help here with $pattern regex

file_put_contents($dir, $new);
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: How come you're not fixing the bugs?

Comment: "there's no way to avoid these useless notices" have you tried finding out why the notices happen in the first place? and if you have: try harder.

Comment: ok... ok... these notices are coming from the mpdf class, which is notorious to generate numerous error notices that have no effect on the PDF that is output - I am using CodeIgniter and because of its logging architecture, there's no way to prevent it from logging all of these errors into the file

Comment: @torr: then change PHP settings and exclude notices from the logs. Not quite the best idea, but it'd stop the junk from being logged in the first place.

Comment: the problem with that is then I lose the chance of seeing other errors that are important for maintaining the application's codebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i '/Notice/ { /Undefined/ { /mpdf.php/ d}}' LOG_FILE
```

More general,

```
A="..." B="..." C="..." sed -i "/$A/{/$B/{/$C/ d}}" FILE
```

will remove all lines containing the strings $A and $B and $C.

Comment: Hm... No. I use sed to delete lines from a file directly... You can use a call to sed to do it.

Comment: from a shell script or from interactive shell , you can call it.